# How to break a context menu into more than one column in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `ContextMenuStip` that contains a dynamically generated list of `ToolStripMenuItem` objects. The problem is that when there are too many of them to fit onto the screen, tiny scroll buttons appear at the top and at the bottom of the list, and scrolling through the list is a bit tedious.

How can I make the menu to automatically break into 2 or more columns so the user does not have to scroll?

Comment: i'm not sure i've seen a menu break into columns since Win98 and that was after unchecking scroll menu in Start properties. That said, i did look around some and came up empty. You might need to do this custom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour was dropped from Windows some while ago -note that Windows Vista/7 use a tree to show programs in the start menu. I suspect that this was because it presents too much data and decision making for the user.

**Are you sure that this is the best way to present the choices to the user?**

If so, then you will probably need a custom menu control which will be quite a lot of work.

- If not, then you should consider how
  you can achieve the same choices with
  other controls. How about a list with
  a filter?
- Is there some natural grouping to the
  items? If so you could split into
  listboxes, comboboxes or trees.
- Does the application need splitting
  into different modes?
- Are the items numbers? - if so a
  numeric up/down control might work

The general approach is to simplify the amount of decision making that the user has to make at any moment.

Spend some time playing with all the controls in the WinForms toolbox to see what works well.

Comment: This seems to be the consensus.