# .Net WinForms - Multi-column context menu

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, contextmenu

I see that this question has been asked, but not in [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833140/can-i-create-a-multiple-column-context-menu-in-net-windows-forms) to [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640907/how-to-break-a-context-menu-into-more-than-one-column-in-winforms) years so here goes:

Is there any way to generate a multi-column context menu in .Net WinForms?

We are trying to change the look from something like [this (single column menu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3DSM.gif) into [this (multi-column menu)](http://support.citrix.com/article/html/images/CTX121903-1.gif).

I am aware that the Windows 98 start menu is not the same as a context menu.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a very bad idea from a UX perspective, find a different UI approach. And probably don't use winforms either.

Comment: I agree with @HighCore that if you need that many items then a menu is probably not the best idea.

Comment: create a user control for yourself and place it inside a `ToolStripDropDown` container and display the `ToolStripDropDown` on left click on the form.

Comment: In terms of whether it makes sense from a UX perspective - I assume MSFT did usability testing/analysis before they opted to put it into windows as the default option. I know that I, personally, preferred multi-column to the alternative.   

In terms of using WinForms vs. WPF - You know that we developers don't always get to choose.